# OpenCv webcam streaming class for WPF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wpf, opencv

My goal is to make a class that wraps the complexity of OpenCvSharp implementation to show a webcam streaming into a `WPF` `Image`. You can find the complete code with a running example (just clone and compile) on [my Github repository](https://github.com/FrancescoBonizzi/WebcamControl-WPF-With-OpenCV).

The important code is this:

```
public sealed class WebcamStreaming : IDisposable
{
    private System.Drawing.Bitmap _lastFrame;
    private Task _previewTask;

    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private readonly Image _imageControlForRendering;
    private readonly int _frameWidth;
    private readonly int _frameHeight;

    public int CameraDeviceId { get; private set; }
    public byte[] LastPngFrame { get; private set; }

    public WebcamStreaming(
        Image imageControlForRendering,
        int frameWidth,
        int frameHeight,
        int cameraDeviceId)
    {
        _imageControlForRendering = imageControlForRendering;
        _frameWidth = frameWidth;
        _frameHeight = frameHeight;
        CameraDeviceId = cameraDeviceId;
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        // Never run two parallel tasks for the webcam streaming
        if (_previewTask != null && !_previewTask.IsCompleted)
            return;

        var initializationSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _previewTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Creation and disposal of this object should be done in the same thread 
                // because if not it throws disconnectedContext exception
                var videoCapture = new VideoCapture();

                if (!videoCapture.Open(CameraDeviceId))
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Cannot connect to camera");
                }

                using (var frame = new Mat())
                {
                    while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        videoCapture.Read(frame);

                        if (!frame.Empty())
                        {
                            // Releases the lock on first not empty frame
                            if (initializationSemaphore != null)
                                initializationSemaphore.Release();
                            _lastFrame = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                            var lastFrameBitmapImage = _lastFrame.ToBitmapSource();
                            lastFrameBitmapImage.Freeze();
                            _imageControlForRendering.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _imageControlForRendering.Source = lastFrameBitmapImage);
                        }

                        // 30 FPS
                        await Task.Delay(33);
                    }
                }

                videoCapture?.Dispose();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (initializationSemaphore != null)
                    initializationSemaphore.Release();
            }

        }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        // Async initialization to have the possibility to show an animated loader without freezing the GUI
        // The alternative was the long polling. (while !variable) await Task.Delay
        await initializationSemaphore.WaitAsync();
        initializationSemaphore.Dispose();
        initializationSemaphore = null;

        if (_previewTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            // To let the exceptions exit
            await _previewTask;
        }
    }

    public async Task Stop()
    {
        // If "Dispose" gets called before Stop
        if (_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        if (!_previewTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

            // Wait for it, to avoid conflicts with read/write of _lastFrame
            await _previewTask;
        }

        if (_lastFrame != null)
        {
            using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory())
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                imageFactory
                    .Load(_lastFrame)
                    .Resize(new ResizeLayer(
                        size: new System.Drawing.Size(_frameWidth, _frameHeight),
                        resizeMode: ResizeMode.Crop,
                        anchorPosition: AnchorPosition.Center))
                    .Save(stream);
                LastPngFrame = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LastPngFrame = null;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        _lastFrame?.Dispose();
    }

}
```

The usage is this:

- Create a WPF page, put an `Image` control in it
- On a "Start" button, create the `WebcamStreaming` class and `await` its initialization:

```
_webcamStreaming = new WebcamStreaming(
    imageControlForRendering: imageControlReference,
    frameWidth: 300,
    frameHeight: 300,
    cameraDeviceId: cameraDeviceId);

await _webcamStreaming.Start();
```

- To stop it, just call: `await _webcamStreaming.Stop();`

Some considerantions:

- I used a `Semaphore` to let the caller await for the first frame, useful to show some loading
- To render the frame to the `WPF` `Image` control I used a synchronous `Dispatcher`, to avoid frame overlapping, but I'm not sure about that. I think it could cause dealocks, but I never noticed one. Maybe could be better to **run & forget** an `InvokeAsync` task?
- I think I should wait for `_previewTask` to complete in `Dispose` method, to avoid disposing something that is in use, but I don't know how to do it without causing deadlocks. Waiting for it would generate deadlock when also waiting for the `Dispatcher.Invoke` operation to complete.

What do you think? Would you make something different? Thanks!